# Proving $B=\{x\in E:\|x\|<1\}$ is not open under the weak topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

> Prove that $B=\{x\in E:\|x\|<1\}$ is not an open set in $E$ under the weak topology $\sigma(E,E^*)$.

A neighbourhood around $x_0$ in the weak topology $\sigma(E,E*)$ is given by $\mathscr{V}=V(x_0;T_1,T_2,...,T_n;\epsilon)\forall i \in \{1,2,3,\ldots,n\}$.

By Hahn-Banach theorem $\|.\|\to\mathbb{K}$ is a functional.
So regarding this functional I can take the sequence ${\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}}\in B $ so that it converges to $x_0\in E$. Then $\forall\epsilon>0,\exists N\in\mathbb{N}:\|x_n-x_0\|<\epsilon$

I need to prove $x_0\in B$

$\epsilon>\|x_n-x_0\|\geqslant\|x_n\|-\|x_0\|\implies \|x_n\|-\epsilon>\|x_0\|\implies 1-\epsilon>\|x_0\|$ so $x_0\in B$ and $B$ is closed regarding the functional $\|.\|\to\mathbb{K}$

I could also have applied Heine theorem since the norm is continuous.

However this is not enough once I need to prove that $B$ is not open regarding all the functionals.

**Questions**:

How do I solve this problem? How do I go on proving for every functional?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be helpful if you explain your notations. E.g. what is $V(x_0; T_1, \dots, T_n;\varepsilon)$ ?

Comment: What are the assumptions on $E$?

Comment: @Thomas This is a common enough notation in the realm of weak topologies: $\{x \in E: \forall 1 \le i \le n: |T_i(x) - T_i(x_0)| < \varepsilon\}$ (where all $T_i$ are in $E^\ast$, $x_0 \in E$ and $\varepsilon>0$ and $n$ some finite natural number); these sets are the local base of neighbourhoods at $x_0$ in the weak topology.

Comment: @StarBug $E$ is an infinite-dimensional normed space at the very least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The norm function is not a functional: it's not linear!

To see $B$ is not open show it has a non-interior point, I pick $0$:

Suppose $0 \in B$ has a basic open neighbourhood $$ 0 \in V(0; T_1, T_2, \ldots, T_n; \varepsilon) \subseteq B\tag{1}$$

Assuming, as we must, that $E$ is infinite-dimensional, we find a non-zero vector  $y_0$ in the common kernel of the $T_i$, as in [your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3277249/4280), then $z_0:=\frac{1}{\|y_0\|}\cdot y_0$ has norm $1$ so is not in $B$, while by construction $z_0$ being a multiple of $y_0$, has all $T_i(z_0) = 0$ and so $z_0 \in  V(0; T_1, T_2, \ldots, T_n; \varepsilon)$ but $z_0 \notin B$ contradicting the inclusion $(1)$.

This means that $0$ is not an interior point of $B$ in the weak topology, so $B$ is not open in that topology.

Comment: Note that because we can pick the scalars before $y_0$ as large as we like, that any basic weak-open set is unbounded in norm. No surprise we cannot write a bounded set as a union of them....